# How do I restrict the user inputs to only numbers?

Tags: c

My program is to find the area of a triangle. How do I restrict user inputs to only numbers?

```
float a, b, c, area, s, dec;       /*Declare variables*/
int m;


printf("Input value of side a : ");     /*User input value of side a*/
scanf("%f", &a);
printf("Input value of side b : ");     /*User input value of side b*/
scanf("%f", &b);
printf("Input value of side c : ");     /*User input value of side c*/
scanf("%f", &c);
```

Answer (score 1):

To see whether `scanf` was able to match the requested input, you must check the return value of `scanf`:

```
printf("Input value of side a : ");
if ( scanf("%f", &a) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "input error\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

However, this code will accept a line of input of the form `3.45idfsgjs`. In that case, `scanf` will match the `3.45` and not extract the rest of the line from the input stream.

If you want to validate the entire line of input, you can use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) instead, as `strtof` has an optional paramter which will tell you how many characters were matched.

```
float a;
char line[100];
char *p;

printf("Input value of side a : ");

//attempt to read a line of input
if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "input error\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

//find newline character
p = strchr( line, '\n' );

//verify that newline character was found
//if not, then line was too long
if ( p == NULL )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "line too long for buffer\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

//remove newline character
*p = '\0';

//attemtpt to match input as floating-point number
a = strtof( line, &p );

//verify that entire line was matched
if ( *p != '\0' )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "unable to match entire line\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

//input was valid, the variable "a" now
//contains a valid number
```

Since this input validation code is rather long and must be called several times in your case, it would probably be appropriate to create a separate function which calls `fgets` and performs the input validation.

However, the above code has inconsistent behavior in that it accepts leading whitespace characters (which are discarded by `strtof`), but rejects trailing whitespace characters.

If you also want to reject leading whitespace characters, then you will have to call [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) on the first character, and reject the input if that function returns true.

If you want to instead accept trailing whitespace characters, then the lines

```
//verify that entire line was matched
if ( *p != '\0' )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "unable to match entire line\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

should be changed to:

```
//verify that at least one character was matched
if ( p == line )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "unable to match number\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

//verify that there are either no remaining characters
//or that all remaining characters are whitespace
while ( *p != '\0' )
{
    if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "unable to match entire line\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    p++;
}
```

---

### Further reading:

[A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)